# How can I compile an 4.2.x version of Guest Additions on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: virtualbox, vim, guest-additions

**I would like to compile the Guest Additions from Virtual Box 4.2.12 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS**. It is required to run gvim properly (see addendum below).

I can confirm that I was able to do so in 13.04 with Virtual Box 4.3.6. After countless hours of rebooting and reinstalling VMs and different Guest Additions I know with 100% certainty, regardless of the source of the bug, that 4.2.12 solved all my partial redraw issues in gvim.

Now in a new 14.04 VM I am unable to compile 4.2.12 and am desperate to get it working. I tried under Virtual Box 5.0.4 and 4.3.30. Heck even installing Guest Additions 4.3.0 (VB 4.3.30, Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) fails.

The compilation fails, on a **fresh** installation of Ubuntu 14.04.3 (with updates) under Virtual Box 5.0.4 and 4.3.30. Either it fails at the shared folder module, or it says:

```
Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed. Not installing
X Window System drivers.
```

Even when I do manage to compile (Guest Additions 4.3.30), it always says:

```
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.
```

I did all the usual tips, to no avail:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove dkms build-essential linux-headers-*
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install module-assistant
```

Is it possible to compile **Guest Additions 4.2.12** at all under 14.04.3 ?

**Addendum**

Why install 4.2.12 you may ask? Well there is a very obscure bug with either GTK or Guest Additions for Ubuntu under a Windows 7 host (both 64 bit, with 3D enabled). There are redraw issues in **gvim** when switching tabs (tabs do not redraw properly) and when moving through the file, where only partial updates happen. gvim is absolutely essential for my workflow. You can see [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32468637/4134275) that I have tried many VMs and Guest Additions versions, to isolate **4.2.12**.

I also compiled gvim 7.3.637 under 14.04.3, and applied the patch from Chris in [issue 91](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/91) to no avail.

Other things that don't solve my gvim issue (without 4.2.12), just in case:

- setting `ttyscroll=0` in vim
- enabling "Qt Window Fix" in Compiz Config Settings Manager
- starting gvim with `--sync`option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-server-1.5.-support is only available from [Virtualbox >= 4.2.28](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-4.2).

So the error we see is related to Ubuntu using a newer XServer version which is not yet supported in older releases of the VirtualBox guest additions (also see [this bug report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12623)).

This is why guest additions version 4.2.12 refuse to compile in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering about such dependencies but had not idea how to find them. So I should be able to compile 4.2.28 and higher in 14.04? Oh well.. so I guess if my gvim issue can't be solved, I would have to install 4.2.12 on top of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS then.

Comment: @faB: did you already try with the latest version 5.0.4? The devs usually do a great job in fixing bugs but sadly some last forever.

Comment: thanks again.. after more fiddling I finally found a workaround in the latest Ubuntu & Virtual Box with Compiz Config Setting Manager > Utility > Workaround > "force full redraw on repaint" setting.